# Why does gcc-10 fail to link with error "error: array section is not contiguous in ‘map’ clause" in 2D array openacc application?

Tags: arrays, c, gcc, gpgpu, openacc

I am trying to compile a basic openacc program in C, using gcc-10. It works fine for one-dimensional arrays, and arrays allocated through "A[N_x][N_y]" but when trying a 2D array allocated using malloc, either contiguous or not, I get an error message upon compiling. The example below fails:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int N_x = 1000;
  int N_y = 1000;
  int i_x;

  // allocate
  double **A;
  A = malloc(N_x * sizeof(double*));
  A[0] = malloc(N_x * N_y * sizeof(double));
  for (i_x = 0; i_x < N_x; i_x++)
  {
    A[i_x] = A[0] + i_x * N_y; // contiguous allocation
//    A[i_x] = malloc(sizeof(double) * N_y);  // non-contiguous allocation
  }
  
  // another example of same error
  // get onto the GPU
  //#pragma acc enter data create (A[0:N_x][0:N_y])
    // get out of the GPU
  //#pragma acc exit data copyout (A[0:N_x][0:N_y])

  // following pragma triggers the "error: array section is not contiguous in ‘map’ clause" error
  #pragma acc parallel loop copy(A[0:N_x][0:N_y])
  for (i_x = 0; i_x < N_x; i_x++)
    A[i_x][i_x] = (double) i_x;

  // free
  free(A[0]);
  free(A);
  

  return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Thank you for your help. Btw, I compile with

```
gcc-10 test2.c -fopenacc
```

on a 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system with this GPU card: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine, but I don't believe GNU supports non-contiguous data segments.  I'll need to defer the GNU folks but do believe that they are developing this support in future versions of the compilers.

For now, you'll need to either switch to using the NVIDIA HPC Compiler (https://developer.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk) or refactor the code to use a single dimension array of size N_x*N_y with a computed index.  Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define IDX(n,m,s) ((n*s)+m)

int main()
{
  int N_x = 1000;
  int N_y = 1000;
  int i_x;

  // allocate
  double *A;
  A = malloc(N_x * N_y * sizeof(double*));
  #pragma acc enter data create(A[:N_x*N_y])

  #pragma acc parallel loop present(A)
  for (i_x = 0; i_x < N_x; i_x++)
    A[IDX(i_x,i_x,N_x)] = (double) i_x;

  // free
  free(A);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, that confirms my suspicions of what was going on here. Agreed that flattening the array is a workaround, but that means the appeal of e.g. moving from openMP to openacc with only minimal code changes is lost. I am still puzzled however why the compiler is not accepting the array as contiguous since all entries of my 2D array are neatly lined up in memory, and the first malloc reserved the entire block ---but I might be using a more loose interpretation of the term (?)

Comment: Btw, also appreciate the plug of the nvidia compiler, which I did download as alternative. I ended up with 'nvcc', which seems to be both different from and an evolved version of the 'pgcc'  (?). It was that confusion that prompted me to stick to gcc at first. I don't think I can just substitute nvcc for pgcc when compiling, but if I had something that takes the same flags as pgcc then that would completely solve the problem (I guess the question is already resolved in the narrow sense by noting that the gcc team hasn't implemented it yet, apart from the meaning of 'contiguous')

Comment: I should disclose that I work for NVIDIA's HPC Compiler Team, formerly called PGI.  We re-branded PGI to NVHPC about 6 months ago.  Though, pgcc's equivalent would be nvc, not nvcc, which is NVIDIA's CUDA C++ compiler.  Note that the pgcc driver still ships with the NVHPC SDK and that nvc still accepts some of the older spellings of the pgcc flags.  Though the only major change in flag name was "-ta=telsa" becomine "-gpu" and that's because we started supporting native language parallelism in C++ and Fortran so wanted to unify the flags.

Comment: About the nvcc, nvc, pgcc compilers: In case someone else got similarly confused, it turned out I was just lazy and assumed I'd done everything needed when downloading the .deb file for NVHPC SDK and installing that. That does provide a directly accessible nvcc because it's in the usual bin directory. However, the other compilers (nvc, pgcc) are actually installed too, albeit in a different directory that still needs adding to the PATH (some subdirectory of /opt/nvidia), see also this link: [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/hpc-sdk-install-guide/index.html).